# How to copy into with cp if destination folder already exists?

Tags: cp

Example...

This is what I want.

```
/tmp $ cp -f -R --verbose /tmp/a /tmp/b
`/tmp/a' -> `/tmp/b'
`/tmp/a/file2' -> `/tmp/b/file2'
`/tmp/a/file1' -> `/tmp/b/file1'
```

This is what I do not want.

```
/tmp $ cp -f -R --verbose /tmp/a /tmp/b
`/tmp/a' -> `/tmp/b/a'
`/tmp/a/file2' -> `/tmp/b/a/file2'
`/tmp/a/file1' -> `/tmp/b/a/file1'
```

How can I let cp behave as if the folder didn't already exist?

(I don't want to delete it beforehand. Just some files from /tmp/a to get copied into /tmp/b without creating a sub folder a inside /tmp/b. So it looks like /tmp/b/file1 /tmp/b/file2 and so on.)

Comment: If this is the real James Mitch who posted this please say so in this accounts profile ;)

Comment: What happens if I or whoever else is using this account will never accept a answer? Will "I" still lose those 100 reputation points?

Comment: yes you would. See this: http://askubuntu.com/users/72629/james-mitch?tab=reputation the rep gets deducted *immediately* when placing a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rsync was invented for this kind of thing.

```
rsync -av --update /source/ /destination
```

NB: Notice that /source/ has a trailing "/" which picks up file1, file2 and not the folder it is in.  /destination doesnt have a trailing. So your solution looks like this:

```
rsync -av --update /tmp/a/ /tmp/b
```

Comment: People _use_ it that way, but it was invented for network transfer.  If you're copying gigabytes of files locally, it's a few times slower it could be.  Some measurements here: http://lwn.net/Articles/400489/

Comment: Using `-W` will tell `rsync` to skip checking for differences, it might improve performance.

Answer (score 11):

The `-T` flag (AKA `--no-target-directory`) does what you want:

```
$ cp -R --verbose -T /tmp/a /tmp/b
`/tmp/a/file1' -> `/tmp/b/file1'
`/tmp/a/file2' -> `/tmp/b/file2'
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming Bash you can do

```
( shopt -s dotglob; cp -f -R --verbose /tmp/a/* /tmp/b/ )
```

What this does is:

1. it will make sure globs (the `*`) catch files with a dot in front. They are considered "hidden" by convention.
2. `*` will expand before `cp` gets to see the command. So if there are two files as in your question the expanded command line will be `cp -f -R --verbose /tmp/a/file1 /tmp/a/file1 /tmp/b/`
3. finally the trailing backslash on the destination makes sure that it copies *into* that folder `/tmp/b/`.

This method also makes sure you don't have to reset the shell option, because it's being run in a subshell. You can achieve similar results by putting it into a script file instead of executing from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cp -r --verbose a/. b
`a/.' -> `b'
`a/./zzz' -> `b/zzz'

$ cp -r --verbose a/. b
`a/./zzz' -> `b/./zzz'
```

I don't think I've seen this described anywhere; I was just trying different possibilities and found one that worked.  For all I know it's a natural consequence of how `/.` and `cp` work.  (As opposed to the syntax for `rsync`, mentioned in another answer, which is explicitly documented as a special case).