# Copy one file to other of same name

Tags: cp

I have 2 folders with same name **(pepe pepe)**. i want to copy the files of pepe to other one without lossing the files of destination .

**how i can do it ?**

copying new files from pepe folder to other folder pepe without lossing any file

thanks

Comment: If they're in different locations , specifying full path should do the trick

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy into with cp if destination folder already exists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250355/how-to-copy-into-with-cp-if-destination-folder-already-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easily you can just use cp command:

```
cp -rn /path-to-first-pepe-dire/* /apth-to-second-pepe-dir
```

**PS:** *I use -r in case you have directories inside so if you don't have you can get rid of*

use `-n` to not  overwrite  an  existing  file

**example:**

first dir `pepe` in your home

second dir `pepe` in your desktop

then command would be

```
cp -rn ~/pepe/* ~/Desktop/pepe
```

Comment: Warning: this will overwrite already existing files with the same name!

Comment: You can add a `-n` ("no-clobber") after the -r, to not overwrite existing files: `cp -rn /path-to-first-pepe-dire/* /path-to-second-pepe-dir`